# Lossy Image Compression Metrics

Tags: image-processing, compression, image-compression, lossy-compression

I'm wondering about what types of metrics I can use for comparing different (lossy) image compression methods (i.e., things other than compression ratio). For example, comparing JPEG, JPEG 2000, and JPEG XR on a set of different images.

Ideally I'd like to do this in a python notebook, but I'm open to any suggestions.

Thank you!

Comment: what metrics do you know already?

Comment: The simplest is to take the average absolute difference between the original and decompressed images. This is a raw measurement, I don't know of any method that would rate the psychovisual (i.e. human-perceived) loss.

Answer (score 1):

I think this boils down to comparing the lossy images to their original, i.e. measuring the loss of image quality.
Measure the difference between the lossy image and its origin, do the same for other lossy images and compare the results.

How this can be done [has been asked before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68818307/determining-lost-image-quality-through-lossy-compression) and I have just added an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71819709/18764404) mentioning some approaches.